# Z-index stacking order glitch - corrects on document click

Tags: css, z-index, gif

Call-to-Action Banner (Position: Absolute, Z-index: 5) frequently shows below an animated gif (Gif container z-index: 1, position: fixed) until I click on the page with the banner in view. This also happens with other elements it should be stacked on top of.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Here's a temporary url with the problem itself http://charming-zoo.flywheelsites.com/

Comment: Looks like a browser issue, its loading fine for me in FF. I don't have to click or anything. Try searching for the issue specific to your browser.

Comment: It is only occurring in chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Adding will-change: opacity to the banners worked.